# Detecting when a key is released

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to check when a key is released, but I can't do so without having an infinite cycle, and this puts the rest of the code on pause. How can I detect if a key is released while running the rest of my program without an infinite cycle? This is the code I found and that I have been using:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int counter=0;
    ofstream myfile;
    short prev_escape = 0, curr_escape = 0;
    myfile.open("c:\\example.txt");
    while(true)
    {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
            curr_escape = 1;
        else
            curr_escape = 0;
        if(prev_escape != curr_escape)
        {
            counter++;
            if(curr_escape)
            {
                myfile <<"Escape pressed : " << counter << endl;
                cout<<"Escape pressed !" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                myfile <<"Escape released : " << counter << endl;
                cout<<"Escape released !" << endl;
            }
            prev_escape = curr_escape;
        }        
    }
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "while running the rest of my program"? First of all, decide when specifically you want to check for the keypress.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard Input & the Win32 message loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441457/keyboard-input-the-win32-message-loop)

Comment: JustJeff, Thanks, I will investigate. Kos, I need it to be checked at all times.

Comment: You are supposed to have a window which gets messages like [WM_KEYUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Do you need a global detection (no matter what the active app is), or should it work only when your application is the active one?

Comment: Paul, it is an Opengl game, where I need to run the whole game, while constantly checking if a key is pressed or released

Comment: You normally test the keyboard from inside your main game loop

Comment: Yes thank you, I solved the problem, I just don't know how to close this post as solved, i'm new.

Comment: @PuértolasLuis Write an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the way you test the return value of `GetAsyncKeyState()` is incorrect. Test for the return value being negative to detect whether or not the key is down. So your `if` should read:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) < 0)
```

If you wish for that code to execute without blocking your main thread, then you'd need to put the busy loop into a separate thread. That's probably still a poor idea because you are running a busy loop.

In a GUI process you would have a window message loop that would be able to receive `WM_KEYDOWN` messages. But you have a console application. In that case you might be best using `PeekConsoleInput` which you would call periodically to check whether or not there is an escape key press waiting in the input buffer. An example of how to do that can be found here: [Intercept ESC without removing other key presses from buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342392/intercept-esc-without-removing-other-key-presses-from-buffer).

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how to explain it, but that solved the problem!

Comment: it didn't worked for me,  it is also works if i will keep holding this key.

Comment: @HaSeeBMiR What doesn't work? I don't think you read the answer carefully enough.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you have to check if keystate is zero like this.`if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) == 0)`

Comment: @HaSee What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: if key is released it state is 0.

Comment: @HaSee That's not what I'm talking about in this answer. It's also wrong. Key is down if and only if GetAsyncKeyState returns negative value.

Comment: i printed the state of key in infinite loop without pressing any key it printed out value 0. and when pressed it printed out **32768**.

Comment: @HaSee GetAsyncKeyState returns a signed 16 bit value and 32768 is outside the range of possible signed 16 bit values. Clearly you are doing something wrong. I can't diagnose it with no code, in comments to a 4 year old question. If you need help, ask a question.

Comment: I was printing with %hu format because some bug with %h format , actually it was in range . I solved it anyways.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0 && shift == false)
    {
        shift = true;
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) == 0 && shift == true)
    {
        shift = false;
    }
```

This is a more refined version that I used in my CLI game which I adopted from Davids answer just now (thank you David, I was racking my brain trying to figure this out myself).  The top executes when shift is pressed, the bottom is executed when shift is released.

EDIT: The bool "shift" has to be initialized to false before hand for this to work.