# Is there a way to detect a key press while Console is asking for User input

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a console app where you can add a person (employee)
When you *add* the employee, the program will ask you for various information, such as name, DOB, etc. However, if you misspell something, you cannot necessarily go back to that line in that moment in time (might implement that later)

Point is, I wanted to give the user the option to press escape, and cancel the entire process of adding the employee.

However, I cannot for the love of god, find any type of way to do this while a user is in the "ReadLine" state. Even if after they enter in information, and the console is in a "WriteLine" state, my logic for pressing escape will not work.

I am trying to find a way to have the program continuously check if the ESC key is pressed EVER at ANY point and if so, it will return to the previous menu (function).

```
        Console.WriteLine(@"****adding employee*****
________________");
        //***Trying to have program continuously check if esc is ever pressed if so, stops the process of adding. 
        do
        {
                        
            Console.Write("name: ");
            first = Console.ReadLine();
            indexFirst = first.IndexOfAny(invalid);

            Console.Write("Last: ");
            last = Console.ReadLine();
            indexLast = last.IndexOfAny(invalid);

            if (indexFirst > -1 || indexLast > -1)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("First or Last name entry has an invalid character");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                AddEmployee();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Generating ID...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            id = Convert.ToString(IdGenerator());
            Console.WriteLine($"ID number: {id}");
            Console.ReadKey();

            Console.WriteLine("Date of birth (MM/DD/YYYY)");

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    birth = DateOnly.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    break;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {


                    Console.Write("Please include the \"/\" symbol to separate the month day and year.");
                }
            }


            Console.Write("Address: ");
            address = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Is the address correct? Type \"yes\" or \"no\". ");
            answerCheckAddress = Console.ReadLine();
            answerCheckAddress = answerCheckAddress.ToLower();
            while (answerCheckAddress == "no")
            {
                Console.Write("\bRe-enter the address: ");
                address = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Is the address correct? Type \"yes\" or \"no\". ");
                answerCheckAddress = Console.ReadLine();
                answerCheckAddress = answerCheckAddress.ToLower();
            }


            Console.Write("Social Security Number: ");
            //social = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            social = Console.ReadLine();
            int socialCheck = social.Length;


            while (socialCheck > 9 || socialCheck < 9)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Social has too many or too few numbers.");
                Console.Write("Please re-enter Social Security Number: ");
                social = Console.ReadLine();
                socialCheck = social.Length;
            }




            employees.Add(new Employee(first, last, id, birth, address, social));
            Console.WriteLine("Employee added...Press enter to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            EmployeeMenu();
        } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

I tried using this readkey as a loop, I tried to use Console.KeyAvailable but it seems that it's not necessarily used for this type of situation.
Would this have to be done using threading? Is it possible to even have the console continuously check a key even if the user is providing input as a string?

Comment: Have you tried this? It's not exactly what you're looking, but I'm not sure it's achievable with ReadLine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996519/listen-on-esc-while-reading-console-line

Comment: What are _ReadLine state_ and _WriteLine state_? Are you new to computer programming or just new to writing Console programs? While a certain amount of data validation should exist, one must balance that with trying to not annoy the user. You should consider the escape key as not yours to use (in your program) - that goes for the _F_ keys (F1, F2, F3, etc...) as well. You'll have to re-think your design.

Comment: Why not just ask user if he/she wants to enter further empoloyees? Something like "Enter next employee? y/n?".

Comment: I am relatively new to programming yes. But what I mean by ReadLine state and WriteLine state is just the actual execution the program is on. For example. 
If my console is literally printing "Enter address" I'm specifying that is literally the console at the "writeLine" instruction at that specific time on that specific line where the program is told to WriteLine("Enter Address"), and the "ReadLine" state is literally when the user of the program has the ability to type what they want to input while the program is on that instruction. That's all I mean really.

Comment: In response to "egeer" I'll have to take a look at that question, it seems on topic so far actually. not sure why I wasn't able to find this specific one out of the 12 other questions I found. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading an entire line, you'd need to read every key-stroke that has happend. So you may use `Console.Read` instead and just append the character if user actually typed something. However be aware that you also need to capture enter in order to continue for the next "type" of input:

```
ConsoleKey key;
StringBuilder currentText;
string[] input = new string[5];
int counter = 0;

do
{
    key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
    if(key == Console.Key.Enter)
    {
        currentText = new StringBuilder();
        input[i] = currentText.ToString();
        i++;
    }
    else
        currentText.Append(key.ToString());
} while (key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Now your `input`-array contains all the information typed in by the user. However be aware about index-ovweflows. Furthermore parsing the data is a bit harder, as you need to check at which index you're currently staying.

Alternativly you could just ask the user, if he/she wants to enter a next employee, which is way easier to implement:

```
String answer;
do
{
    adress = ...
    socialNumber = ...;
    Console.WriteLine("Next employee? y/n");
    answer = Console.ReadLine();
} while (answer != "y");
```

Comment: I could have the user continue adding Employees but that's not really the issue at hand. I want them to be able to STOP what they are doing all together, as soon as they hit ESC. Like, abort everything. For Example, If the user is in the middle of typing an employee's address, as soon as they hit escape, it breaks the loop, or, skips all further instructions to go back to a previous menu. Meaning, they cannot finish adding the employee, it just gets rid of the information per se. Like writing a sentence on a sheet of paper, crumbling  it up and throwing it away.